# How to get min date using oracle database date table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select, oracle10g

[image]

here is my sql query

```
select e.event_name,
    min(dt.start_date) as start_date,
    min(dt.start_date)||'-'||max(dt.end_date) as FromTo
from event e join
    date_table dt
on e.e_id = dt.e_id
group by e.event_name;
```

I want to get upcomming events. For that, I use  `MAX(dt.end_date)>=sysdate` then i got the upcomming events. But my problem is, when an event happens today, tomorrow and day after tomorrow, I display start date as "today"(minimum start date). 
But when tomorrow comes, still I showed start date as previous date. Because minimum start date is yesterday. i want to display tomorrow date as the start date.

How should I change my code?

Comment: `@user2763589` whrew is your code..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a where clause.

```
select e.event_name,
    min(dt.start_date) as start_date,
    min(dt.start_date)||'-'||max(dt.end_date) as FromTo
from event e join
    date_table dt
on e.e_id = dt.e_id
where dt.start_date >=sysdate
group by e.event_name;
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you are using min/max here.

If you want to see your next 10 upcoming events (from today) you might want to try something like this :

```
select * 
from (
    select  e.* , dt.start_date , dt.end_date
    from    event e , date_table dt 
    where   e.e_id = dt.e_id 
    and dt.start_date > sysdate 
    order by dt.start_date)
where rownum < 10
```

Comment: yes I can get upcoming events using this query. But my problem is As a example when an event happens 10,12, 20, and 25. Assume today is 10. So today i want to display 10. Tomorrow I want to display 12. When 12 is less than current date this means it is a past date then I want to display 20 so on.. Can you help me..

Comment: I found the answer. 

        select m.E_VENUE,m.E_NAME,min(d.D_START_DATE) min_st_dt,m.E_ID 
        from event m,date_table d 
        where d.E_ID in(
        select distinct d.E_ID 
        from date_table d 
        where d.D_END_DATE>trunc(sysdate)) 
        and  d.D_END_DATE>trunc(sysdate) and m.e_id = d.e_id 
        group by m.E_ID,m.E_NAME,m.E_VENUE ORDER BY min_st_dt;